# Poisson Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poisson-distribution

Using Poisson Limit Theorem derive an asymptotic probability distribution of n wins (getting 4 correct numbers out of 49) in one lottery (of course many people play the lottery). I only know how to determine the probability of getting 4 out of six, which is $$\frac{1}{\binom{49}{4}} \sim 4,7 * 10^{-6}$$ but I don't know how to aplly this theorem.

Comment: Suppose a quarter of a million $M = 0.25 \times 10^6$ people play the lottery, then the number $X$ of winners has distribution $X \sim BINOM(250.000,\; p = 4.7(10^{-6}))$ with $E(X) = Mp = 1.175.$ This is approx $X \sim POIS(\lambda=1.175).$ Thus the probability of no winners is $P(X = 0) = e^{-\lambda} =  0.3088..$ and $P(X = 1) = 0.3629.$ What is $P(X = 2),$ so that two winners split the prize?

Comment: More precisely $1/{49 \choose 4} = 4.719742 \times 10^{-6},$ so it's more like $\lambda = 1.18$ and some of the other numbers above are slightly incorrect.